Gimp showing submenus in Greek characters
After I installed the Gimp on my machine running Windows 10 Enterprise, submenus such as the 'tool options' are shown with Greek characters (as far as I can tell the words are English):

I had first installed it with Chocolatey, which can be considered non-standard, and instead I then used the installer from gimp.org directly.
Gimp still shows the Greek characters, so I guess this is related to my system setup. The clock in the taskbar also has a square as the hour-minute separator, so something is not right. Has anyone else come across this? And is there a solution, e.g., installing more fonts?

Does Windows have multiple languages installed, and which? You could try to test Windows integrity by running the commands Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth and then sfc /scannow.

Might be related: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/3104 Do you have Standard Symbols PS font in your system?

Thanks for your comment @harrymc - it has Dutch installed from work and I have added English UK. I have also installed fonts, but they are Helvetica and the like, not symbols. Running the command did not change things.

Thanks @Destroy666, I had seen that post but the screenshots there show symbols in text added to pictures. In my case it is the interface that is switched - when I add text to a picture it shows letters not symbols.

Doesn't matter. Similar bug can occur in various places. Please answer about the font. And if yes, try uninstalling it to see what happens.

No, when I search (in the 'Personalise' screen when I right-click on the desktop) for Symbol I get 7 fonts, but nothing with 'Standard' or 'PS'. 2 of the 'Symbol' fonts, Cousine-Symbol and Tinos-Symbol, show English text in Greek characters ("A cool summer breeze awakens the trees" and "The starry night brightens our dreams", respectively). So should I delete (1 of) those?
